# Regex to find all lines between start and end

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I am trying to get all lines between a line that matches a specific string until the occurrence of end line. The beginning pattern and end pattern could be in different places in the same file. My intention is to get the block of lines between the multiple occurrences. Basically, my file could like below

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ckjsdnvjn" (ID number, Type varchar2)
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON TRIGGER_NAME
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := SYSTIMESTAMP;
ELSE
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := :OLD.CREATED_D;
END IF;
:NEW.MODIFIED_D := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  END;
/

CREATE TABLE kjjknvfskjn 
(
  ID NUMBER(19,0) NOT NULL,
  GRADE VARCHAR2( 4 ) NOT NULL,
  MODIFIED_D TIMESTAMP,

  CONSTRAINT jnflkvndflkn PRIMARY KEY( ID )
);

CREATE SEQUENCE kcnvlfnvlfnlk;

CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ME(ticket varchar2, note varchar2) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jknsfjknv(
    cnkj,
    kknvlfn
  )
  VALUES (
    SYS_CONTEXT('lknvl','kvnldfkn'),
    '(kljkcsn: ' ||  lkdnv || ') ' || lknv
  );
END ME;
/
```

Expected Output:

Match 1:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ckjsdnvjn" (ID number, Type varchar2)
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON TRIGGER_NAME
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := SYSTIMESTAMP;
ELSE
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := :OLD.CREATED_D;
END IF;
:NEW.MODIFIED_D := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  END;
/
```

Match 2:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ME(ticket varchar2, note varchar2) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jknsfjknv(
    cnkj,
    kknvlfn
  )
  VALUES (
    SYS_CONTEXT('lknvl','kvnldfkn'),
    '(kljkcsn: ' ||  lkdnv || ') ' || lknv
  );
END ME;
/
```

My pseudo code is as follows, however I doesn't get the lines between the second matched line (CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ME) since there is additional parenthesis. Is there any better way to get the desired output?

```
    with open(local_file, 'r') as f:
        textfile_temp = f.read()
        lines = textfile_temp.splitlines()
        STRING = 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER'
        SEARCH_END_STRING = 'end;'
        for line in lines:
            if re.search(STRING, line, re.IGNORECASE):
                line = line.strip()
                line = line.replace('(', '\(')
                line = line.replace(')', '\)')
                print line
                SEARCH_PATTERN = r'(' + line + ')(.*?)(' + SEARCH_END_STRING + ')'
                SEARCH_REGEX = re.compile(SEARCH_PATTERN, re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL|re.MULTILINE)
                match = SEARCH_REGEX.search(textfile_temp)
                print match.group()
```

Error:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ME\(ticket varchar2, note varchar2\) AS
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `re.findall` --> `Lookbehind & Lookahead`

**Demo:**

```
import re
for i in  re.findall(r"(?<=CREATE OR REPLACE).*?(?=\/)", s, flags=re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL):
    print("CREATE OR REPLACE" + i)
    print("---")
```

**Output:**

```
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ckjsdnvjn" (ID number, Type varchar2)
  BEFORE UPDATE OR INSERT ON TRIGGER_NAME
  FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
IF INSERTING THEN
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := SYSTIMESTAMP;
ELSE
  :NEW.CREATED_D  := :OLD.CREATED_D;
END IF;
:NEW.MODIFIED_D := SYSTIMESTAMP;
  END;

----
 CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER ME(ticket varchar2, note varchar2) AS
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO jknsfjknv(
    cnkj,
    kknvlfn
  )
  VALUES (
    SYS_CONTEXT('lknvl','kvnldfkn'),
    '(kljkcsn: ' ||  lkdnv || ') ' || lknv
  );
END ME;

----
```

Comment: Thanks @Rakesh, Works like a charm

Comment: in some cases, I need to actually match between the entire line and /, so instead of just searching for 'CREATE OR REPLACE', i am looping through line  by line ie., 'CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER "ckjsdnvjn" (ID number, Type varchar2)' escaping it and search between the whole line and /. But the challenge here is that sometimes the whole line is repeated somewhere else in the same file, so re.findall gives me 2 blocks. Is there anyway to skip the re.findall if the match was already found?